# Top div cover text in bottom div

Tags: html, css

I have tried many unsuccessful things to make this work. Too many to list. How can I make the white div cover the yellow text in the bottom div?

```
<div id="bottom">This is some text</div>
<div id="top"></div>

#bottom{
  background:blue;
  height:60px;
  color:yellow;
  font-size:45px;

}

#top{
  background:white;
  height:20px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/verimekile/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Can the markup be changed or just the CSS?

Comment: Either one can change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `position relative` (or absolute) on the #top div

```css
#bottom {
  background: blue;
  height: 60px;
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 45px;
}
#top {
  background: white;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom">This is some text</div>
<div id="top"></div>
```

The reason why it wasn't covering the text in the first example was because both elements were **unpositioned** and participated in the **same stacking context** - where the backgrounds are painted on first (most further back) layer - with the background of the #top element appearing above the background of the #bottom element - as it appears later in the source, and the text is painted on a layer above the backgrounds (see the [full details in the spec here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers))

By adding **positioning** (relative or absolute) to the #top div we can ensure that it will be painted above the #bottom div (see rule #6 from the above quoted spec)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working code:

```css
#bottom{
    background: blue;
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 45px;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
#top{
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom">
    <div id="top">This is some text</div>
</div>
```